# if condition with math expression

Tags: conditionals

I would like to use a math expression with if condition. e.g: \x*\y > \m*\n

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\def\x{3}
\def\y{3}
\def\m{2}
\def\n{4}
\typeout{\x,\y}
\typeout{\m,\n}

\typeout{"test"}
\ifnum{\x*\y > \m*\n}
    \typeout{"greater"}
\else
    \typeout{"less"}
\fi
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Current code compile error:

```
3,3
2,4
"test"
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.10 \ifnum{
            \x*\y > \m*\n}
```

What correct way to write such if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. TeX does not allow for arithmetic in primitive conditionals;
2. `\ifnum` doesn't want the test in braces.

The second part is easy to fix; for the first part you can use `\inteval`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\x{3}
\def\y{3}
\def\m{2}
\def\n{4}
\typeout{\x,\y}
\typeout{\m,\n}

\typeout{"test"}
\ifnum\inteval{\x*\y} > \inteval{\m*\n}
    \typeout{"greater"}%
\else
    \typeout{"less"}%
\fi
\stop
```

The console will print

```
3,3
2,4
"test"
"greater"
```

But you shouldn't be using `\def` at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\intcompareTF}{mmm}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineinteger}{mm}
 {
  \int_const:cn { c_lucky_integer_#1_int } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\useint}{m}
 {
  \int_use:c { c_lucky_integer_#1_int }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOn

\defineinteger{x}{3}
\defineinteger{y}{3}
\defineinteger{m}{2}
\defineinteger{n}{4}
\typeout{\useint{x},\useint{y}}
\typeout{\useint{m},\useint{n}}

\typeout{"test"}

\intcompareTF{ \useint{x} *\useint{y} > \useint{m} * \useint{n} }
 {\typeout{"greater"}}
 {\typeout{"less"}}

\stop
```

With these more powerful tools, you *can* do arithmetic in the test. And you don't risk to overwrite important commands using `\def`.

The output is exactly the same as before.

Comment: Thanks, any packages needed? I got error: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \ifnum\inteval
                   {\x*\y} > \inteval{\m*\n}

Comment: @lucky1928 Add `\usepackage{xparse}` in the meantime, while you update your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the package `etoolbox`.
This allows you to write:

```
\ifnumgreater{\x*\y}{\m*\n}{cond. true}{cond. false}
```

#### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\x}{3}
\newcommand{\y}{3}
\newcommand{\m}{2}
\newcommand{\n}{4}
\typeout{\x,\y}
\typeout{\m,\n}

\typeout{"test"}
\ifnumgreater{\x*\y}{\m*\n}{
    \typeout{"greater"}
}{
    \typeout{"less"}
}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\ifnum` primitive accepts two numbers without braces and with `<` or `>` or `=` between them. You can expand to these two numbers by the eTeX primitive `\numexpr`:

```
\ifnum \numexpr\x*\y > \numexpr\m*\n \relax TRUE \else FASLE\fi
```